# Одноименные методы с различными возвращаемыми значениями

Tags: c#

Есть ли способы использовать одноименные методы с одинаковыми входными параметрами, но различными возвращаемыми значениями?
Допустим есть методы

```
public string use_reflection (string param)
{
}
public list<string> use_reflection (string param)
{
}
```

В методе я использую механизм рефлексии для вызова других методов по их имени

```
Type thisType = this.GetType();
MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod("тут имя метода");
answer = theMethod.Invoke(this, params_obj)
```

Соответственно различные методы возвращают различные по типам результаты, так как в C# возвращаемое значение не является сигнатурой метода, то для описанного алгоритма придется создавать методы аналогичные `use_reflection` для каждого типа возвращаемого результата или есть способы обойти это?

Comment: Нельзя объявить функции отличающиеся только возвращаемым значением: _already defines a member called 'use_reflection' with the same parameter types_

Comment: По-моему, лучше всегда возвращать из `use_reflection` `List<String>`, а в самом методе проверять что вернул `.Invoke()` и одиночную строку заменять на список из одной строки.

Comment: @Regent, либо вопрос неполный, либо проблемы такой нет, потому что _Нельзя объявить функции отличающиеся только возвращаемым значением_

Comment: @Grundy я об этом написал в вопросе, просто хотел узнать возможно ли обойти это?

Comment: @Grundy это понятно. Поэтому я и предлагаю сделать один метод, в котором будут скрыты все эти непотребства с рефлексией и который  будет возвращать `List<String>`.

Comment: @Regent это лишь пример, может вернуть не только строковые значения

Comment: @e1s, нет, я не увидел где вы это в вопросе написали: я только отметил что таких методов быть не может, соответственно суть вопроса отсутствует

Comment: но, но, возможно здесь подойдет `generic`: `public T use_reflection<T> (string param)
{...`

Comment: @Grundy вот здесь - "так как в C# возвращаемое значение не является сигнатурой метода"

Comment: @e1s, да, видать как-то ускользнуло от внимания :-)

Comment: @e1s, внутри себя функции выполняют одинаковые действия? или каждая функция выполняет абсолютно разные?

Comment: @e1s если вы собираетесь возвращать всё подряд, то сделайте `public Object use_reflection`. Я, кстати, не в курсе: а `.Invoke()` что возвращает?

Comment: @Regent, _object_, любые методы получения значения в рефлексии возвращают  _object_

Comment: Еще можно сделать метод с out: public void use_reflection (string param, out string result)

Comment: @Vlad, а что это даст?

Comment: @Grundy вот и славненько. Тогда можно прямо так и возвращать.

Comment: @Grundy это позволит затолкать возвращаемое значение в сигнатуру метода, что даст возможность писать перегрузки с разными типами

Comment: @Vlad, как вариант, а как потом получить это возвращаемое значение с помощью рефлексии?

Comment: @Grundy а если метод возвращает массив, то при использовании рефлексии вернется `object` ? или `object[]` ?

Comment: @e1s, а почему просто не вернуть object?

Comment: @e1s не понял вопроса, но наверняка _object_

Comment: @e1s `Object` вернётся.

Comment: @Grundy [Вот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652503/how-to-pass-transfer-out-parameter-as-reflection-visual-studio-extensibility) ответ Скита на этот вопрос.

Comment: @Vlad, ага, посмотрел уже :-)

Comment: @Grundy Так и не удалось по-человечески вставить ссылку. :)

Comment: @Vlad `[text](link)` без пробелов

Comment: @Grundy если я правильно понял то возвращается объект, который я могу привести к любому типу через `.... as List<string> например?` Только не понятно успешно будет это приведение или нет.

Comment: @e1s, да, именно так

Comment: @Grundy немного не понял все равно - допустим есть метод, который возвращает массив строк например, я вызываю этот метод используя рефлексию, получаю object  и пишу `... as int` то что будет в этом случае?

Comment: @e1s, в данном случае должен быть _Exception_, кстати, не уверен что `as` со _Value_ типами можно использовать

Comment: @Grundy `InvalidCastException`, надо полагать?

Comment: @Regent, скорее всего :-)

Comment: @e1s, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Например, так:

```
class Base
{
    public string use_reflection(string param)
    {
        return "";
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    new public List<string> use_reflection(string param)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Доступ либо через явный каст

```
var d = new Derived();
List<string> r1 = d.use_reflection(null);
string r2 = ((Base)d).use_reflection(null);
```

либо через рефлексию:

```
var methods = typeof(Derived).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                             .Where(mi => mi.Name == "use_reflection");
foreach (var mi in methods)
    Console.WriteLine(mi.ReturnType);
```

Comment: а вот вопрос: если объект типа `Derived` кладем в переменную `Base` - вариант с рефлексией не сломается?

Comment: @Grundy: По идее нет, для рефлексии важен runtime-тип.

Answer (score 2):

Я менее ООПшный вариант предложу. Для возврата значения из метода используем out-параметры. А потом дергаем метод через рефлексию:

```
class MethodsContainer
{
    public void Method(string param, out string result)
    {
        result = "Hello, world!";
    }
    public void Method(string param, out List<string> result)
    {
        result = new List<string>();
    }
}

static T CallMethodFromContainer<T>(MethodsContainer container, string param)
{
    object[] arguments = new object[] { param, default(T) };

    typeof(MethodsContainer)
        .GetMethod("Method", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(T).MakeByRefType() })
        .Invoke(container, arguments);

    return (T)arguments[1];
}
```

Ну и использование:

```
var result = CallMethodFromContainer<List<string>>(container, "param");
```